# How to group clases in CSS - Tailwind

Tags: html, css, sass, less, tailwind-css

I am trying to group clases so the code will be cleaner and legible. In the [documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) of Tailwind it talks about "@apply", that can be used for this objective but I am using the CDN and therefore this is not working for me. So my question is, **¿Is there any form I can accomplish what I am looking for?** Maybe by using SASS/SCSS or LESS?

Here is an example of what I wnat:

```
<ul class="md:flex md:items-center z-[-1] md:z-auto md:static absolute bg-gray-800 w-full left-0 md:w-auto md:py-0 py-4 md:pr-0 pr-7 md:pl-0 pl-7 md:opacity-100 opacity-0 top-[-400px] transition-all ease-in duration-200">
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="px-4 py-6 md:py-0 hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent text-white duration-500">
    <a href="#" class="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="px-4 py-6 md:py-0 hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent text-white duration-500">
    <a href="#" class="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="px-4 py-6 md:py-0 hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent text-white duration-500">
    <a href="#" class="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <button class="md:w-auto w-full bg-transparent text-white font-[Poppins] duration-500 px-6 py-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800 border border-white border-dotted rounded-lg">
    Log In
  </button>
  <button class="md:w-auto w-full bg-yellow-500 text-white font-[Poppins] duration-500 px-6 py-2 md:mx-4 hover:bg-yellow-600 rounded-lg">
    Sign In
  </button>
</ul>
```

---

```
<ul class="nav-elemnts">
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <button class="button-login">
    Log In
  </button>
  <button class="button-signin">
    Sign In
  </button>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tailwind encourages you to use components. Instead of copy pasting the classes all over the place, you should use a system that allows you to create and use components.

Since your question is HTML + CSS only, you don't really have the right tools for this. But if you were using a scripting language like JS, Python, PHP etc., you could create components from elements and reuse them. Since I am familiar with React framework, I can show an example of that:

```
function NavElement(props) {
  return (
    <li class="px-4 py-6 md:py-0 hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent text-white duration-500">
      <a href={props.href} class="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500">{props.children}</a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

and then use it as

```
function NavElements() {
  return (
    <ul class="md:flex md:items-center z-[-1] md:z-auto md:static absolute bg-gray-800 w-full left-0 md:w-auto md:py-0 py-4 md:pr-0 pr-7 md:pl-0 pl-7 md:opacity-100 opacity-0 top-[-400px] transition-all ease-in duration-200">
      <NavElement href="/">Home</NavElement>
      <NavElement href="/services">Services</NavElement>
      <NavElement href="/about-us">About us</NavElement>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

As you can see, with this approach, you extract the huge list of modifiers into a small component that you can use multiple times without much repetition in the code.

You are free to choose any tool, language, system that will enable making components. That is what Tailwind kind of expects you to do.

Comment: I see what you are trying to tell me but the case is that i want to group the clases and then do what you are saying me. I mean, I want to have a amount of clases in a stylesheet where each class is a group af clases of Tailwind. So at the end I will have my custom clases using Tailwind. I dont know if you undertand what I am looking for, let me know if you don't and I will try to improve the question.

Comment: That's not what you *should* do in Tailwind. If you group your classes in CSS (even when using @apply) you're basically going back to normal CSS - having to come up with class names, managing selectors etc. Tailwind is there so that you don't have to do that. Consider that Tailwind might not be the best tool for you personally if you don't like one of the fundamental building blocks of it - using utility tokens - which is totally fine, lot's of people don't like it.

Comment: So this is not a "problem" and if I have a long line of classes is not bad?. I am new with Tailwind, and when I start coding I thougth that this was not like "good practice" to have a pile of classes.

Comment: No, it's not a problem. It can be an issue for maintenance if you have to maintain them manually, which is why we create small reusable components and not copy paste the classes everywhere, but the list is definitely not a problem on its own. Either you "get used" to it, or you will dislike it, so the subjective feeling plays a big part it this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I understand better how to use Tailwind and the objective of it

Answer (score 3):

I understand with your headache when reading long lines of css class and repetition to write them to some component.

Gratefully TailwindCSS has a way to organise classes of components in separated file, so you can reuse your css classes. Here is the way:

Create file named **main.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    @layer components {
      .card {
        background-color: theme('colors.white');
        border-radius: theme('borderRadius.lg');
        padding: theme('spacing.6');
        box-shadow: theme('boxShadow.xl');
      }
      /* ... */
    }
```

Then you can use it in your components:

```
<!-- Will look like a card, but with square corners -->
<div class="card rounded-none">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Official document: [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles)

Good article describe about it: [link](https://bloggie.io/@kinopyo/organize-your-css-in-the-tailwind-style-with-layer-directive)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried doing:

```html
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer components {
      .some-class {
        @apply px-4 py-6 md:py-0 hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent text-white duration-500;
      }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I try it and the vs code shows me this alert: "Unknown at rule @layercss(unknownAtRules)" and it dosn't apply anything to the element with the class I stablish

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for SASS/LESS type approaches, but I think that adds additional complexity that you may not need. I think some simple JS would be a good candidate solution.

The way I've done it is to sort of replace CSS or StyledComponents with a JSON object of class names and a utility function to turn these into one big string.

First, the utility. Put this somewhere shared:

```
// turns a JSON object's values into a single string (keys are irrelevant)

export const classify = (classes) => Object.values(classes).join(' ')
```

Then in a file like styles.js that's next to the index.js, I'd have:

```
import { classify } from 'shared/utils'

export const nav = classify({
  base: 'absolute bg-gray-800 w-full left-0 pr-7 pl-7 py-4 opacity-0 top-[-400px] z-[-1]',
  animation: 'transition-all ease-in duration-200',
  larger: 'md:flex md:items-center md:z-auto md:static md:w-auto md:py-0  md:pr-0 md:pl-0 md:opacity-100'
})

export const navItem = classify({
  base: 'px-4 py-6 hover:bg-yellow-500 text-white',
  resp: 'md:py-0 md:hover:bg-transparent',
  anim: 'duration-500'
})
```

This is just like your CSS file. Yes, you have to name the variables, but you'd also have to name your components doing it the other way and this keeps things way less littered with files. You also get the benefit of seeing your HTML structure rather than a bunch of component names (which are more than likely just divs, smh). Also, you can have any number of key/values in your JSON, however you see fit to organize for reduced cognitive load while maintaining.

Then, the HTML/JSX:

```
import * as styles from './styles'

export default Component = (props) => (
  <ul className={styles.nav}>
    <li className={styles.navItem}> ... </li>
    <li className={styles.navItem}> ... </li>
    <li className={styles.navItem}> ... </li>
  </ul>
)
```

The thing I like about this approach is that it's very similar to the CSS workflow and the JSON objects allow you to organize your class names in any way you want (ideally not doing it nested or you'll need a more complex `classify()`). Using components, you still have big long strings to mess with which is annoying when you have tens of classes applied. You can even do these in the same file if you'd like, it's just JavaScript.

You can even create utility styles/classes this way and concat them with template strings:

```
import * as utilStyles from 'utils/styles'
import * as styles from './styles'

<section className={`${utilStyles.shadowPanel} ${styles.mainSection}`>
...
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to group tailwind classes. One with nodejs and another without nodejs ie using CDN. Its so simple with script, you can just create a variable with multiple tailwind classes and insert that into DOM.

You can use vanilla js to group the classes and apply on the DOM. Insert the script at the end of HTML code as shown.

```html
<body>
<ul class="nav-elemnts">
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-element">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <button class="button-login">
    Log In
  </button>
  <button class="button-signin">
    Sign In
  </button>
</ul>
<script>
let nav-link="text-x1 md:hover:text-yellow-300 duration-500"
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")).forEach((el)=>el.className=nav-link)
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @apply method is not so helpful as pseudo-classes can't be included.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "@layer components" + "@apply"  works well in my nextjs/tailwind project

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .login-page {
        @apply bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900;      
    }
    .login-container {
        @apply flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto;
    }
    .login-title {
        @apply flex items-center mb-6 text-2xl font-semibold;
    }
    .login-card {
        @apply w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0;
    }
}
```

The HTML is as follows

```
export default function Login() {
return (
    <section className="login-page">
        <div className="login-container">
            <a href="#" className="login-title">
                SineWave Engineering
            </a>
            <div className="login-card">
                <div className="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
```

Answer (score -3):

You should add 'group' class to parent and after work with group subclasses:

```
<div class="group p-4">
  <p class="group-hover:bg-red-400">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

after this code if you hover on div element, p elements backgroundColor will be change to red.

Comment: I think he meant how to group tailwindcss classes like @apply (but on cdn), not how to use the group class